# LinearLayout height returns -1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Getting height of `LinearLayout` return -1.

**Code :**

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.create_trip_layout);
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams param = layout.getLayoutParams();
Log.d("Layout height : ", param.height + "");
```

Comment: Try changing `android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams` to `android.Widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams` @Akash

Comment: Gives `android.view.LinearLayout cannot be resolved to a type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `layout.getHeight();` it returns its height.

From the doc

```
returns:
    The height of your view, in pixels.
```

to work you have to wait until Android has drawn the root of your Layout.

Comment: It worked. But can you tell me why `param.height` returned -1?